# ansible poll и async

Tags: ansible

если например запустить poll 0 и async 10 в ansible , и передать какую то команду на выполнение, если она не успеет выполниться то будет прервана?(что внутри там произойдет)

Comment: Добавьте пример того, что пробовали и какой результат.